# Send array list to Twig View without headers in Symfony 2

Tags: json, symfony, propel

I need help sending query list to Twig without headers. I have already query my data and I am stuck. I had to have this data in JSON structure.

This is name of my root: 'AdminBundle:Note:viewPdf.html.twig'
And here is name of query class in propel - it is empty now: MnNoteCommentQuery.

Here is my code:

```
$noteQuery = MnNoteCommentQuery::create()->find();
$responsed = new JSonResponse($noteQuery);
return $this->render('AdminBundle:Note:viewPdf.html.twig', array('notes' => $responsed));
```

Comment: `JSonResponse` class is a **Response** class, which means it's designed to be returned form controller and not used in view layer (Twig in this example). Use simple `json_decode`/`json_encode` if you need to work with JSON data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use [json_encode](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/json_encode.html) in twig

```
return $this->render('AdminBundle:Note:viewPdf.html.twig', array('notes' => $notes));
```

Twig:

```
{{ notes | json_encode() }}
```

You can customize json representation by implementing [JsonSerializable](http://php.net/manual/en/class.jsonserializable.php) interface

Comment: It's almost work as i want :D but now i have that kind of data in twig:
{"0":{"posx":"190px","posy":"287px"}}
and the best solution is have array like this:
notes={"posx":"190px","posy":"287px"},{"posx":"190px","posy":"287px"}
Can i control this somehow?

Comment: this number in the begining each row normally display name of the bundle. It is possible to delete it from this array?